# How to design notation for a mapping of elements belonging to different sets?

Tags: notation

I am trying to design a particular notation, described as follows:

$X$ is a finite set of elements.

$s_k, k = 1...n, n < 10$ are few, different, mapping function.

Each $s_k$ function maps elements of $X$ into 3 disjoint sets: $U$, $D$ and $I$
.

For each function $s_k$, if an element $x$ is put in $U$, $s_k(x) = 1$; if it is put in $D$, $s_k(x) = -1$; finally, if it is put in $I$, $s_k(x) = 0$.

The $s_k$ functions are designed in such a way that if each element can be mapped to $1$ by at most one function, and can be mapped to $-1$ by at most another (**NOT** by the same) function. However, each element can be mapped to $0$ even if mapped to $1$, $-1$ or $0$ by another function (but **NOT** by the same function).

Is there a particular notation for such case?

Thanks

Comment: Usually downvote requires also a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of 2 disjoint sets $A,B$, which together form a partition of their disjoint union $Y=A \cup B$, one speaks about the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the subset $A$ as the function $\chi : Y \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $\chi(x)=1$ for $x \in A$ and $\chi(x)=0$ for $x \in B=X-A$.

Given 3 disjoint sets $U,D,I$ which together partition their disjoint union $Y = U \cup D \cup I$, you could perhaps speak about a *3-fold characteristic function* $\chi:Y \to \{-1,0,1\}$ defined by 
$$\chi(x)= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x \in U$} \\
0 & \text{if $x \in D$} \\
-1 &\text{if $x \in I$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks, the term 3-fold characteristic function is somewhere used as a standard? I searched a bit but I did not find anything related. However, thanks, it was what I was searching for.

Comment: No, I do not believe there is any such standard. I merely suggested it as a possibility for you.